# Meaning of " go with the billet "

Tags: meaning, idioms

Here is the passage :

Upstairs, ghosts have been
seen flitting about the house. These I
haven’t seen, but they’ve been reported
for years, and apparently **they go with
the billet**. Now, I wouldn’t mention any
of this except that we have an unusual,
persistent problem

Comment: What's the definition of 'billet"??

Comment: I haven't seen this turn of phrase before (the only written instance in Google Books is the cited example). But my guess is it's the same as idiomatic / figurative ***comes** with the **territory***. In this context, it just means the ghosts "come with house" (they're a natural "part / aspect" of the place). Or feasibly "the billet" is a more figurative reference to the narrator's *current (recently changed) circumstances* (perhaps some new course of action he's engaged with, whether willingly or not).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote is from [Haunting of West Point](https://edandlorrainewarren.com/haunting-of-west-point/) and concerns the U.S. army.

A **billet** is accommodation assigned to soldiers. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/billet) has

> **billet**
> a place for soldiers to stay in for a short time
> *Our billets were about a mile out of town.*

So "go with the billet" means that the ghosts reside, or appear,  at that location.